# How to marshal arrays inside a struct to a native dll

Tags: c++, f#, interop

I am attempting to wrap a native C++ dll in a .Net core dll.

As a test (and to keep things simple) I have a small C++ dll that exports a single function that takes a pointer to a struct and returns one element from an array within the struct.

```
struct param {
    int i;
    double d;
    double array[3];
};

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) double GetSecondValue(param* p);

double GetSecondValue(param* p)
{
    return p->array[1];
}
```

In F# I have a matching(?) struct

```
module Structures

open System.Runtime.InteropServices
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type Par = 
    struct
        val mutable i : int
        val mutable d : float
        [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)>]
        val mutable da : float[]
    end
```

and then a simple program to test

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open Structures

[<DllImport("Dll1")>]
extern double GetSecondValue(Par & p);


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let mutable p = new Par()
    p.d <- 1.0
    p.i <- 5
    p.da <- [|3.0;7.0;9.0|]
    let result = GetSecondValue(&p)
    Console.WriteLine(result)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The single double and integer values come through ok but the array looks like the pointer has got messed up
[image]

I suspect my marshaling is incorrect. Can anyone offer any advice (or even better a good example) on how this should be done.

Comment: Following inspiration from another stackoverflow question I also added 
`ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.R8)>]` to the marshaling for the array and now it's working.

Whether it was that or a mix up with the plethora of binaries I have caused by the different locations a binary can end up when building from the command line and VS, I'm not sure.

It would still be good to know if there is anything disastorously wrong with my approach above.